# Reprogram basic one-button garage door remote?

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have an older basic one-button GENIE Intellicode ACSCTG Type 1 garage door remote that I'd like to use with our garage door opener.

Stock photo:

[image]

Is this thing reprogrammable?  Is there a way to make it work with our opener, without having to reprogram the opener and all the other remotes?

The GENIE opener has two different model numbers on the sticker:

PMX500IC/B

ACSR1G

There is a "LEARN CODE" button on the back of the opener.

Comment: What model is your garage door opener? Most common openers made in the last 20+ years can easily add an additional remote, without needing to reprogram any of the previous ones

Comment: @MosheKatz Added that info to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your opener and this remote are compatible, and programming is simple using the "learn code" button.

Full instructions from genie (PDF): https://www.geniecompany.com/files/en/programming/g1t-remote (The picture in these instructions is the newer version, but the instructions are the same for the older version that you have.)

1. Press and release the "learn code" button. The red LED will blink rapidly.
2. Press and release the button on the remote. The LED will stop blinking and remain on.
3. Press and release the button on the remote. The LED will turn off.
4. Press and release the button on the remote a third time. The opener will operate.

This programming process will not affect any other remotes that have previously been programmed.